# How to rename an attribute name with python LXML?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

It's fairly well documented how to get and set the *value* of an attribute with LXML, but is there a way to rename the *name* of an existing attribute?

The goal is to get from

```xml
<element old="cheese"/>
```

to

```xml
<element new="cheese"/>
```

What I am currently doing is a bit convoluted — deleting the attribute and then re-adding it with a new name and the old value:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

doc = StringIO('<element old="cheese"/>')

tree = etree.parse(doc)
elem = tree.getroot()

attr_value = elem.attrib['old']
del elem.attrib['old']
elem.attrib['new'] = attr_value
```

Is there a way to rename an attribute directly instead of deleting and re-adding with a new key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I wish I could upvote your question twice because you gave a minimal, reproducible example that I could copy/paste/run. Those new to stack overflow should take note! I suppose it's because users that have been around as long as you and I don't ask as many questions.

I don't think what you're doing is that convoluted, but since `.attrib` is a dict you could do something like this instead:

```py
elem.attrib['new'] = elem.attrib.pop('old')
```

Full example:

```py
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

doc = StringIO('<element old="cheese"/>')

tree = etree.parse(doc)
elem = tree.getroot()

elem.attrib['new'] = elem.attrib.pop('old')

print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Printed output...

```xml
<element new="cheese"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The below does the same with python "out of the box" python xml lib - [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) .

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<element old="cheese"/>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
root.attrib['new'] = root.attrib.pop('old')
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<element new="cheese" />
```

Comment: The “renaming” of the attribute is exactly the same in ElementTree and lxml. My answer, other than the “full example” is the same for both.

Comment: I agree. By the end of the day the actual question is - how to replace a key in a dict... My answer just shows that an external lib is not a must.